# Want to update my old html css ,js site with React , $('some').owlCarousel, throws an error Type error , owlCarousel is not a function

Tags: reactjs

Want to update my old HTML, CSS ,js site with React.

I make the components for HTML and integrate js also, but when I am trying to import and run owl carousel in jquery, like `$('some').owlCarousel`, throws an error Type error,

> owlCarousel is not a function